# How to break column as title in a HTML table

Tags: html, laravel

I want do report with HTML and put one column as title and supress repetition. I'm using Laravel 5.8.

This is my view code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
<div class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Leito</th>
<th>Nº Atendimento</th>
<th>Dt. Atendimento</th>
<th>Paciente</th>
<th>Idade</th>
<th>CID Principal</th>
<th>CID</th>
<th>Médico</th>
<th>Dias internado</th>
<th>Observação</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($analytic as $patient)
<tr><td colspan="11"><strong>Setor: </strong>{{ $patient->setor }}</td></tr>
<tr class="{{ $patient->corlinha }}">
<td>{{ $patient->leito }}</td>
<td>{{ $patient->atendimento }}</td>
<td>{{ $patient->dtatendimento }}</td>
<td>{{ $patient->paciente }}</td>
<td>{{ $patient->idade }}</td>
<td>{{ $patient->cidp }}</td>
<td>{{ $patient->cid }}</td>
<td>{{ $patient->medico }}</td>
<td>{{ $patient->dias }}</td>
<td>{{ $patient->observacao }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is my result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZdwX.png)

When "Setor" is same i need agroup them.

I need something like this:

[Result that i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpKAd.png)

Thank´s

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to `groupBy` your collection. I am giving an example.

Controller Code:

```
public function index()
    {
        $$analytic = Model::all()->groupBy('setor');

        return view('view', compact('analytic '));
    }
```

In blade your table will look like something:

```
<table>
    @foreach ($analytic as $key => $data)
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10">{{ $key }}</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($data as $patient)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $patient->leito }}</td>
                <td>{{ $patient->atendimento }}</td>
                <td>{{ $patient->dtatendimento }}</td>
                <td>{{ $patient->paciente }}</td>
                ...........
                ...........
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Hope you can now work around to get your desired result. Read Laravel documentation about collection groupBy [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-groupby).

Comment: It would benefit you greatly to use the Laravel relationships instead.  This is the power of the framework - take 5 minutes to make the relationship, and you can do exactly as you wish.

Comment: I'm using sql query. This is my controller: https://paste.laravel.io/03b52785-f68e-4394-b0e4-4f3cf16aa366

If I group by sector, I can never group because all other columns will always be different.
So if I change the html code, for your example, will it be right?

Comment: @Watercayman I am using third party database, I am not the owner. I just need to show a report.

Comment: Gotcha.  Too bad, this would be simple if you could coordinate models to the framework.